# Не работает подбор предметов на основе системы Raycast

Tags: c#, unity3d

Написал код для подбора объектов, если камера наведена на объект с нужным тэгом. Выводится ошибка(Object reference not set to an instance of an object). Скрипт прикреплен к модели персонажа.  Ошибка ссылается на эту строчку:

`Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector2(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2));`

Весь код:

```
public GameObject Object;
public Camera cam;

private void Update()
{
    RaycastHit hit;
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector2(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2));
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 1f))
    {
        if (hit.collider.tag == "Object")
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
            {
                Object.SetActive(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Эту ошибку можно нагуглить.